# How do I work with a REST API in Java that returns a zip file?

Tags: java, api, rest, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I am familiar with the basics of making a GET request in Java using the HttpURLConnection class. In a normal situation where the return type would be a JSON, I'd do something like this:

```
    URL obj = new URL(myURLString);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inpLine;
        StringBuffer resp = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inpLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            resp.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(resp.toString());                          
    } else { System.out.println("Request failed");
```

However, the current endpoint I'm trying to work with sends back a zip file containing various types of files. The 'Content-Type' in that case would be 'application/octet-stream'. Hitting that endpoint with the above code results in a mess of symbols (not sure what it's called) written to the console. Even in Postman, I see the same, and it only works when I use the 'Send & Download' option when making the request, which prompts me to save the response and I get the zip file.

Any help on how to hit the API and download the returned zip file through Java? Thank you in advance.

Edit: What I intend to do with the zip file is save it locally and then other parts of my program will work with the contents.

Comment: A zip file is a binary. So you can't use a character based _reader_ (you are using an `InputStreamReader`) to read the content. Take the input stream as is (because they are nbyte based).

Comment: What do you need to do with that zip file? Do you need to save it somewhere or you are interested in a content (in what’s inside) ?

Comment: I need to save it somewhere. There is a parameter on the endpoint where I can specify where to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try this API:

```
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(con.getInputStream())) {
        
    ZipEntry entry; // kinda self-explained (a file inside zip)

    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
         // do whatever you need :)
         // this is just a dummy stuff
        System.out.format("File: %s Size: %d Last Modified %s %n",
                    entry.getName(), entry.getSize(),
                    LocalDate.ofEpochDay(entry.getTime() / MILLS_IN_DAY));
    }
}
```

In any case, you get a stream, so you can do all the stuff that java IO API allows you to do.

For instance, to save the file you can do something like:

```
// I am skipping here exception handling, closing stream, etc.
byte[] zipContent = zis.readAllBytes();
new FileOutputStream("some.zip").write(zipContent);
```

To do something with files inside zip you can do something like:

```
 // again, skipping exceptions, closing, etc.
 // also, you'd probably do this in while loop as in the first example
 // so let's say we get ZipEntry 
 ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
 
 // crate OutputStream to extract the entry from zip file
 final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/someDir/" + entry.getName());
 
 
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int length;
 
 //read the entry from zip file and extract it to disk
 while( (length = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     os.write(buffer, 0, length);
 }

 // at this point you should get your file
```

I know, this is kinda low level API, you need to deal with streams, bytes, etc., perhaps there are some libs that allows to do this with a single line of code or something :)

Comment: I didn't know about this is API, thank you! However, I'm still looking for a way to save either the entire zip file, or ideally save a ZipEntry, so I can iterate through all and only save the ones I want based on some condition.

Comment: @Ars Updated :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only thing to note for reference is that readAllBytes() may not be inherited by the ZipInputStream class depending on the jdk version. Nonetheless, I'm not interested in saving the whole zip so this works for me. Much appreciated! @ikos23